# How can i filter the json by a specific length and style this with ngClass?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular-material

I work with mat-table in which I output data from a JSON. Now I would like to filter out all records that have an ID of length 5 and then style them in my  via ngClass. Can you tell me how this works?

My Code:

```
// JSON-EXAMPLE

{
    "success": true,
    "myJSON": {
        "myList": [
  {
                "id": 102000,
                "name": Alex,
                "age": 15
            },
            {
                "id": 10200, // length 5
                "name": Peter,
                "age": 30
            },
            {
                "id": 12345, // length 5
                "name": Andrew,
                "age": 34
            },
           {
                "id": 31322323,
                "name": Clark,
                "age": 40
            },
]
}
}
```

```
// TS

public highlightedSpecialRows = null;

  private loadData() {
this.myService.getData(param).subscribe(
(resp: any) => {
const data = resp.success ? resp.myJSON.myList : null;
if (null !== data && data) {
.....
const filterIdLength = 5; // define the length to filtering
this.highlightedSpecialRows = data.filter((d) => `${d['id']}`.length >= filterIdLength); // Here I wanted to filter the ids by length 5, unfortunately it didn't work. What is the reason?
}
}
);

}
```

```
// HTML
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index;" [ngClass]="{ 'highlightedRows': this.highlightedSpecialRows"}>....</td>
```

Comment: Hey, Please check my answer and let me know. Best wishes :-)

Answer (score 0):

To assign class to every cell you can try the code given below. I have used simple class and method to do that.

**CSS:**

```
.one {color: red}
.two{color: yellow}
.three { color: green}
.fourorabove { color: blue}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ng-container >
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngClass]="myClass(element)"> 
          {{element[column.id]}}
        </td>
</ng-container>
```

**TS:**

```
myClass(element){
    if(element['id'].toString().length=='1'){
      return 'one';
    }
    else  if(element['id'].toString().length=='2'){
      return 'two';
    }
    else  if(element['id'].toString().length=='3'){
      return 'three';
    }
     else  if(element['id'].toString().length>='4'){
      return 'fourorabove';
    }
  }
```

**NOTE:** Please check the demo link in the [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-cell-mat-table-rvmyng?file=app%2Ftable-basic.component.ts).

Comment: Good example. However, I have the problem that I get the JSON from API and would like to filter out the 5 digit ids via data.filter(...) first and style them afterwards. The ids do not appear in my columnDef at all. Have only name and age.

Comment: Just remove the Id column for `columndef` and load `datasource` on api response return successful. Additionally, if you want to filter 5 digit id and then style them then you can do that ` if(element['id'].toString().length>='5'){
      return 'five';
    }`

Comment: @and.neo2020 If you still facing problem them please create a sample in stackblitz. Then I might have a chance to solve your problem.